# Mask or not mask when converting int to byte array?

Tags: c, arrays, bit-manipulation

Say you have a integer and you want to convert it to a byte array. After searching various places I've seen two ways of doing this, one with is shift only and one is shift then mask. I understand the shifting part, but why masking?

For example, scenario 1:

```
uint8 someByteArray[4];
uint32 someInt;

someByteArray[0] = someInt >> 24;
someByteArray[1] = someInt >> 16;
someByteArray[2] = someInt >> 8;
someByteArray[3] = someInt;
```

Scenario 2:

```
uint8 someByteArray[4];
uint32 someInt;

someByteArray[0] = (someInt >> 24) & 0xFF;
someByteArray[1] = (someInt >> 16) & 0xFF;
someByteArray[2] = (someInt >> 8) & 0xFF;
someByteArray[3] = someInt & 0xFF;
```

Is there a reason for choosing one over the other?

Comment: In this particular code the mask is redundant.  Other variations of code might need it. Also, some compilers give bogus warnings if you don't mask.

Comment: @YuHao Fixed, thanks!

Comment: If you don’t need the mask, eliminating it could save you four `and` machine instructions.

Comment: @Lorehead seems unlikely

Comment: If the compiler gives some warnings when not using the mask, explicitly casting the result may help, e.g. `someByteArray[1] = (uint8)(someInt >> 16);`

Comment: If `CHAR_BIT == 9`, which is theoretically possible, and used to occur in practice historically, then the masking makes sure things work.  Some DSP chips have `CHAR_BIT == 16`. For systems with `CHAR_BIT == 8` (most current systems), it isn't necessary.

Comment: @M.M C implementations don’t *have* to have types exactly eight bits wide, so if the smallest element of addressable memory is wider than that, you might need the bitmask. In a realistic scenario, it depends on whether the optimizer realizes that truncation makes the bitmask redundant. Probably not worth worrying about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`uint8` and `uint32` are not standard types in C.  I assume they represent 8-bit and 32-bit unsigned integral types, respectively (such as supported by Microsoft compilers as a vendor-specific extension).

Anyways ....

The masking is more general - it ensures the result is between `0` and `0xFF` regardless of the actual type of elements `someByteArray` or of `someInt`.

In this particular case, it makes no difference, since the conversion of `uint32` to `uint8` is guaranteed to use modulo arithmetic (modulo `0xFF + 0x01` which is equal to `0x100` or `256` in decimal).   However, if your code is changed to use variables or arrays of different types, the masking is necessary to ensure the result is between `0` and `255` (inclusive).

With some compilers the masking stops compiler warnings (it effectively tells the compiler that the expression produces a value between `0` and `0xFF`, which can be stored in a 8 bit `unsigned`).   However, some other compilers complain about the act of converting a larger type to an 8 bit type.   Because of that, you will sometimes see a third variant, which truly demonstrates a "belts and suspenders" mindset.

```
uint8 someByteArray[4];
uint32 someInt;

someByteArray[0] = (uint8)((someInt >> 24) & 0xFF);
someByteArray[1] = (uint8)(someInt >> 16) & 0xFF);
someByteArray[2] = (uint8)((someInt >> 8) & 0xFF);
someByteArray[3] = (uint8)(someInt & 0xFF);
```